# Can't acces super class public members with sub class variable

Tags: c++, subclass, superclass, public-members

So if I have a following class Super:

```
class Super {
public:
    string member = "bla bla";
    void doSth() { cout << member; }
};
```

And a class Sub that inherits Super:

```
class Sub : Super {
public:
    string member2 = "bla bla 2";
};
```

Than, when I have a Sub object, I can't reach members of Super even thought they're public.

```
using namespace std;
int main(){
    Sub sub;
    cout << sub.member2 << endl;
    cout << sub.member << endl; // error: public Super::member is inaccessible 
    sub.doSth(); // error: public Super::doSth() is inaccessible 
}
```

But why if they're public? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: you have `private` inheritance, but you want `public` inheritance

Comment: thanks, that's it, I didn't about for that

Comment: If you are going to ask questions about inheritance in C++, it would be a good idea to use the terms `base` and `derived`, rather than `superclass` and `subclass`.

Comment: You may want to read these links: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/basics-of-inheritance , https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance , https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/private-inheritance

Answer (score 5):

You are inheriting from `Super` privately.  If you do not mention the access level for inheritance, that is the default for `class`es in C++.  However, note that `struct`s have the default set to `public`.

Change your code to

```
class Sub : public Super {
public:
    string member2 = "bla bla 2";
};
```

And then `member` will be visible

Comment: mkay, would be cool to have a name for classes and structs (other than just classes), that would avoid some confusion about class vs struct